# Cannot instantiate automation variable

Tags: c#, dll, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I need to register 3rd party dll and then, use it as automation variable in navision.
I registered it by regasm "path/to/dll". I can see this library in subtype window and chose it as variable. When i try to run button which should run the code, runtime exception occured. It sounds like: "There can't be created OLE formant or automation server identified by {DF5505B6-7551-424C-B4F6-CBE380C60DB1}1.3{GUID FROM MY ASSEMBLY.CS}:NavisionInterface.CurrencyHelper. Check if your OLE formant or automation server is correctly installed or registered. This is how my code looks like:

```
[Guid("DC9690B5-BB82-42A1-8C64-AF3E2CA38FD6")]
public interface NavisionHelper
{
    double GetCurrency(string code, string year, string month, string day);
    void MakeFilesActualization();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class CurrencyHelper : NavisionHelper
{
    public CurrencyHelper() { }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public double GetCurrency(string code, string year, string month, string day)
    {
        var dbOp = new DatabaseOperations();
        return dbOp.getCurrency(code, year, month, day);
    }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void MakeFilesActualization()
    {
        NBP nbp = new NBP();
        DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations();
        var existingTableNames = db.GetTableNames();
        nbp.DownloadData(existingTableNames, curr => db.AddCurrencyData(curr));
    }
}
```

and this is how I try to run in navsion 2009:

```
IF( ISCLEAR(obj)) THEN
 CREATE(obj,TRUE,TRUE);
obj.MakeFilesActualization();
CLEAR(obj);
```

Comment: Could it be that your automation server is unable to find one or more of its dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the application doesn't know where to find your dll file.  Use /codebase option when you're using reagasm.

Comment: could you point to some documentation to justify the /codebase option?

Comment: here is the documentation from msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx which everyone already found it. but, the other day i just had the same problem, the scenario was like that: the app that uses the dll (my exemple: MS NAV 5) was only searching in the current folder, the location of the executable. If you don't put the dll there, you must specify the absolute path of it using codebase.